# Moq expectations on the same method call with different arguments

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to set up a mock object in a loop that will return different values for a function call with different arguments:

```
var myMock= new Mock<IInterface>();
for (int i = 0; i < fromKeys.Count; ++i)
{
    var value= new[] {new[] {1.0 + i}};
    _values.Add(value);
    myMock.Setup(x => x.Provide(fromKeys[i])).Returns(new Sth(fromKeys[i], value));
}
_myObject = myMock.Object;
```

but it crashes when I am calling `Provide` with the first key in the production code (and not during test setup):

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, ref SignatureStruct sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at Moq.Evaluator.SubtreeEvaluator.Evaluate(Expression e)
   at Moq.Matchers.LazyEvalMatcher.Matches(Object value)
   at Moq.MethodCall.Matches(ICallContext call)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Moq.ExtractProxyCall.HandleIntercept(ICallContext invocation, InterceptStrategyContext ctx)
   at Moq.Interceptor.Intercept(ICallContext invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IBrownianProviderProxy.Provide(BrowniansKey keys)
   at MyCode.....
```

How can I set it up?

Comment: Does this have something to do with closure?  Try adding a line inside the loop before the `myMock.Setup()` line: `int j = i;` and then using `j` in your mock setup instead of `i`.

Comment: How are you setting up _values?

Comment: Looks like _values is a problem. Can you provide the code for setting up _values?

Comment: @AdarshShah, values are actually created in the same loop, see edit. The crash is when I call the methods on the mock,  not when I set it up.

Comment: Provide more code so that I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BenAllred, well spotted! If you put your solution into an answer than I will accept it.

Comment: @Grzenio: Glad that helped.  Input as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a closure problem.  `x => x.Provide(fromKeys[i])` isn't evaluated until later.  By the time it's evaluated later, `i` == `fromKeys.Count`, which is out of bounds of the array.  If that doesn't make sense, I suggest reading more about closure.  The easy solution, though, is to add a line so your code looks like this (in the `for` loop)

```
for (int i = 0; i < fromKeys.Count; ++i)
{
    int j = i;
    myMock.Setup(x => x.Provide(fromKeys[j])).Returns(new Sth(fromKeys[j], _values[j]));
}
```